# Gnuplot and Octave giving scrollbar error

Tags: octave, gnuplot

The following error is occurring in both Gnuplot and Octave at the newest installation:

error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Please update your post with the following information: Ubuntu version, Octave version, steps to reproduce your error.

Comment: @N0rbert This question is fine the way it is without being updated because user3281447 commented below my answer that it solved the problem as follows: *Thank you so much. It appears that your method works. Thanks again.*

Answer (score 1):

This error can be solved by changing line 30 in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc` as shown below. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo -i  
cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps  
cp mate-panel.rc mate-panel.rc.bak # backup mate-panel.rc file before editing it  
nano mate-panel.rc
```

Now mate-panel will be open for editing in nano text editor. Scroll down with the <kbd>↓</kbd> key and change the following line:

```
class "GtkScrollbar"              style "murrine-scrollbar"
```

by replacing the string "murrine-scrollbar" with "scrollbar" so that it looks like this:

```
class "GtkScrollbar"              style "scrollbar"
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes in mate-panel.rc. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Logout in the terminal from root back to normal user.

```
exit
```

Now you will be able to use gnuplot and Octave without getting an error message that says: `error: invalid string constant "murrine-scrollbar", expected valid string constant`

Comment: Thank you so much. It appears that your method works. Thanks again.